# AmbiguousRuleException when there is no ambiguity

Tags: snakemake

In this Snakemake script the `rule all` defines a target, and there are three other rules that claim this target as an output:

```py
rule all:
    input:
         "target.txt"


rule from_non_existing_file:
    input:
        "non_existing_file.txt"
    output:
        "target.txt"


rule broad_input:
    output:
        "target.txt"


rule narrow_input:
    input:
        "optional_input.txt"
    output:
        "target.txt"

ruleorder: narrow_input > broad_input
```

The file *non_existing_file.txt* doesn't exist, so the `rule from_non_existing_file` should not be regarded by Snakemake. The `rule broad_input` has no input files, so it always can produce the output, and the `rule narrow_input` can produce the output whenever the file *optional_input.txt* exists. To resolve the ambiguity between broad and narrow inputs, the ruleorder is defined.

Whenever the file *optional_input.txt* exists, the script prefers the `rule narrow_input`:

```
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1       narrow_input
        2
```

This script works *most of the times*, but sometimes it fails:

```
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules narrow_input and broad_input are ambiguous for the file target.txt.
Consider starting rule output with a unique prefix, constrain your wildcards, or use the ruleorder directive.
Wildcards:
        narrow_input:
        broad_input:
Expected input files:
        narrow_input: optional_input.txt
        broad_input: Expected output files:
        narrow_input: target.txt
        broad_input: target.txt
```

Here Snakemake ignores the fact that the `ruleorder` directive is defined, and advises to define it again.

To confirm this behavior I've designed the test script below:

```py
import os

def test_snakemake():
    for i in range(100):
        rcode = os.system("snakemake --cores=1 --printshellcmds --forceall --dry-run")
        assert(rcode == 0)
```

This test fails within first 20 iterations with high confidence.

I've conducted some experiments and got surprising results:

- The test pass if *optional_input.txt* doesn't exist
- The test pass if any of the three rules is removed

This problem is confirmed on two different Windows machines with Snakemake versions 5.7.4 and 6.5.3.

My question is whether that is a Snakemake bug. Is there another explanation of this behavior?

Comment: Your issue could be related to this: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/970